# Autosize Multiline UILabel with Word Wrapping in Swift

Tags: swift, uilabel, multiline, word-wrap, autosize

I have a collection view with UILabels that are constrained to the width and height of their container cell. Each UILabel has customizable text.
I would like this text to shrink and word wrap in order to fit the text in the largest size possible. I've tried many, many threads, read solutions in objc, and nothing works. I can't figure this out. What we see here is just a minimum font size with Truncate Tail, which is supposed to work, but that 'd' keeps getting cut and I can't figure out why.

Anyone have some tips for me? I've tried a few programming solutions but nothing has worked so far.

*This is what I am getting:*

[image: What I am getting]

*This is what I want:*

[image: What I want]

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. I created an extension for UILabel to handle the issue.
You can try to adapt it to your needs.

```
func adjustFontSizeToWidth() {

        enum Constants {
            static let fontDecrement: CGFloat = 1.0
            static let minimumFontSize: CGFloat = 6.0
        }

        var characterSet = CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines
        characterSet.insert(charactersIn: "-")
        let words = text?.components(separatedBy: characterSet)

        var largestWord = ""
        var largestWordWidth: CGFloat = 0

        words?.forEach { word in
            let wordSize = (word as NSString).size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font])
            let wordWidth = wordSize.width

            if wordWidth > largestWordWidth {
                largestWordWidth = wordWidth
                largestWord = word
            }
        }

        while largestWordWidth > bounds.width && font.pointSize > Constants.minimumFontSize {
            font = font.withSize(font.pointSize - Constants.fontDecrement)
            let largestWordSize = (largestWord as NSString).size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font])
            largestWordWidth = largestWordSize.width
        }
    }
```

But make sure that the label has proper bounds when you call `adjustFontSizeToWidth()` on it. For example, you can override `layoutSubviews()`.

Comment: Nice, works great! Also, if you do it with labels in reusable elements like cells, don't forget to reset the font size before assigning a new text.

Answer (score -1):

This may work for you

```
var label = UILabel()
label.text = "Harvard Hills" // "Willis 7", "Arbs"
label.numberOfLines = 2
label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.6 . // Important - set minimum scale factor

// Now an answer to your question
let numOflines = label.numberOfLines
```

Now, refresh your label, using `layoutSubviews` or `layoutIfNeeded` from view controller and reduce font size using number of lines.

```
if numOflines > 1 {
     label.font = // reduce font size (by 4 or 8 points)
}
```

Here is result (I created designable label and set condition there):

[image]